# routing based on conditions in angular8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to implement routing as - having 'name' for `gsearch` in `router-outlet`. When `gsearch` conditions matches `<router-outlet name="gsearch"></router-outlet>` should open the view rest `router-outlet` should not show any view.

Either "gsearch" routlet-outlet or other router-outlet should work at a time based on routing condition.

How to achieve this goal?

## app.component.html

```
// if, else if, else conditions type

<router-outlet name="gsearch"></router-outlet> <=== gSearch opens here
<router-outlet name!="gsearch"></router-outlet> <=== rest routing should be here
```

## routing.ts

```
{
        path: '',
        component: GSearchComponent,
        outlet: "gsearch"
 }
 {
        path: '',
        component: abcComponent,
        outlet: "abc"
 },
 {
        path: '',
        component: cdeComponent,
        outlet: "cde"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the concept of **Router Guard** to allow the route.
For example:
In app-routing.module.ts call **canActivate** property like this

```
{
        path: '',
        component: GSearchComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {name: 'gsearch'}
 }
```

In **Authguard** component implement your query like

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot, protected router: Router) { }

    canActivate() {
        let name = route.data.name as string;
        if (name !== 'gsearch') {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Make sure to import **AuthGuard** in your **providers** of **app.module.ts**

Answer (score 0):

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet name="gsearch"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="default"></router-outlet>
```

**routing.ts**

```
{
  path: '',
  component: GSearchComponent,
  outlet: "gsearch"
}
{
  path: '',
  component: abcComponent,
  outlet: "default"
}
{
  path: '',
  component: cdeComponent,
  outlet: "default"
}
```